# Error setting comptr to winrt::UserControl::Tag()

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, c++-winrt, cppwinrt

**Update:**
I used Richard's suggestion to fix the setting of Tag. But I am having some issues using the getter for Tag and using the ***.as***/***try_as*** operator on it.

```
class DerivedController : public winrt::implements<DerivedController, Controller> {
 public:
    DerivedController() {}

    virtual ~DerivedController() {}

    static winrt::com_ptr<DerivedController> from(const winrt::FrameworkElement& control) {
        return control ? control.Tag().try_as<DerivedController>() : nullptr;
    }
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt\winrt/base.h(8013): error C2440: 'static_cast': cannot convert from 'winrt::impl::producer<D,I,void> *' to 'D *'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            D=`anonymous-namespace'::DerivedController,
1>            I=winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable
1>        ]
1>        and
1>        [
1>            D=`anonymous-namespace'::DerivedController
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt\winrt/base.h(8013): note: Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt\winrt/base.h(8012): note: while compiling class template member function 'D &winrt::impl::produce_base<D,I,void>::shim(void) noexcept'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            D=`anonymous-namespace'::DerivedController,
1>            I=winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt\winrt/base.h(7777): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'D &winrt::impl::produce_base<D,I,void>::shim(void) noexcept' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            D=`anonymous-namespace'::DerivedController,
1>            I=winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt\winrt/base.h(7737): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'winrt::impl::produce_base<D,I,void>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            D=`anonymous-namespace'::DerivedController,
1>            I=winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt\winrt/base.h(7777): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'winrt::impl::produce<D,winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            D=`anonymous-namespace'::DerivedController
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt\winrt/base.h(4088): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'D *winrt::get_self<To,winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable>(const I &) noexcept' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            D=`anonymous-namespace'::DerivedController,
1>            To=`anonymous-namespace'::DerivedController,
1>            I=winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt\winrt/base.h(2387): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'winrt::com_ptr<D> winrt::impl::as<To,winrt::impl::IUnknown>(From *)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            D=`anonymous-namespace'::DerivedController,
1>            To=`anonymous-namespace'::DerivedController,
1>            From=winrt::impl::IUnknown
1>        ]
1>note: see reference to function template instantiation 'winrt::com_ptr<D> winrt::Windows::Foundation::IUnknown::as<`anonymous-namespace'::DerivedController>(void) const' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            D=`anonymous-namespace'::DerivedController
1>        ]
1>note: see reference to class template instantiation 'winrt::com_ptr<D>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            D=Controller
1>        ]
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt\winrt/base.h(10615): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'winrt::com_ptr<winrt::impl::IContextCallback>' being compiled (compiling source file
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt\winrt/base.h(10349): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'winrt::com_ptr<winrt::impl::IServerSecurity>' being compiled
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt\winrt/base.h(10308): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::chrono::time_point<winrt::clock,winrt::Windows::Foundation::TimeSpan>' being compiled
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt\winrt/base.h(6462): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'winrt::com_ptr<winrt::impl::IMarshal>' being compiled
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt\winrt/base.h(210): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::array<uint8_t,8>' being compiled
```

Controller is constructor as:

```
auto controller = winrt::make<Controller>().as<Controller>();
```

DerivedController is constructed as:

```
DerivedController dController{};
```

DerivedController used to be like this in c++/cx:

```
ref class DerivedController sealed : public Controller {
    internal : explicit DerivedController(Windows::UI::Xaml::FrameworkElement ^ &control)    
        : Controller(control) {}   

    static DerivedController ^   
        from(Windows::UI::Xaml::FrameworkElement ^ control) {   
            return control ? dynamic_cast<SvgCanvasController ^>(control->Tag) : nullptr;   
        }
}
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong, the error seems to be related to how the classes are defined. Would appreciate any thoughts on it!

**Original:**
In C++/CX, I used to be able to do:

```
ref class Controller {
    Controller() {
        container = ref new UserControl();
        container->Tag = this;
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

When I try to convert this to C++/WinRT, direct conversion would like this:

```
class Controller : public winrt::implements<Controller, winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable> {
    Controller::Controller() {
        winrt::UserControl container;
1===>    container.Tag(this);
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

> Controller is a hand-authored class (no idls) whose definition looks like this:

```
class Controller : public winrt::implements<Controller, winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable> 
{
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

But I get an error at (1):

```
Error   C2664   'void winrt::impl::consume_Windows_UI_Xaml_IFrameworkElement<D>::Tag(const winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable &) const': cannot convert argument 1 from 'Controller *' to 'const winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable &'
```

1. Is it possible to set a Com pointer to Tag using some interop with ABI?
2. Is there anything else I am missing?
3. Is this the right approach? Or is there a way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Is it possible to set a Com pointer to Tag using some interop with ABI?

If you want to convert the code `container->Tag=this`; in C++/CX to the corresponding code in C++/WinRT, you could try to pass `*this` as the parameter instead of using interop with ABI , like this:

```cpp
class Controller : public winrt::implements<Controller, winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable>
{
    public:
        UserControl container;
        Controller::Controller()
        {
            container.Tag(*this);
        }
        ……
};
```

> 2. Is there anything else I am missing?

You did a good job, but maybe we can pay attention to the defference of this between C++/CX and C++/WinRT. Here we use `*this` instead `this`.

> 3. Is this the right approach? Or is there a way around it?

If you want to get the object added into `Tag` property, then the approach is right.  You can try this code:

```cpp
Controller cc{};
UserControl uc = cc.container;
auto item1 = uc.Tag();
        
auto item2=  item1.try_as<Controller>();
auto item3 = item2.get();
UserControl uc2 = item3->container;
if (uc = uc2)
{
   int t = 1;
}
```

**Update:**

You can use **static_cast** to implement the conversion from Controller pointer to DerivedController pointer and change the return type of **from** method as DerivedController* like this:

```
static DerivedController* from(winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::FrameworkElement const& control) 
{
    auto con = static_cast<winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::FrameworkElement>(control);
    if (con != nullptr)
    {
        auto it1=con.Tag();
        auto it2 = it1.try_as<Controller>();
        Controller* cc = it2.get();
        DerivedController* der = static_cast< DerivedController* >(cc);
        return der;
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

Then call the **from** method:

```
Controller cc{};
DerivedController dController{};
DerivedController* aa = dController.from(cc.container);
```

Comment: Hi Richard, I updated the issue with some errors I am facing after applying this. Would appreciate your thoughts on this!

Comment: Hi @ssn, I modified the answer, please kindly check it.

Comment: Actually it looked like I had to explicitly derive from IInspectable and not just implicitly based on this: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20200827-00/. I hadn't tried your approach.

Answer (score 0):

You've gotten most of the way there, but it's time to dig into what actually happens under the hood when calling `as<To>()/try_as<To>()`. You may already know that they are a wrapper for [QueryInterface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/unknwn/nf-unknwn-iunknown-queryinterface(refiid_void)). The only difference between the two is that `as<To>()` converts `QueryInterface` failure into an exception, while `try_as<To>()` returns null on failure. (For brevity, I'll refer to just `as<To>()` for the remainder)

So now we know that we're calling `QueryInterface`, but it takes a `GUID`, not a template type argument. C++/WinRT translates this for us with a type trait, `winrt::guid_of<T>`, that associates a uuid with a type. When the type `To` is a projected interface, or a raw ABI interface declared with the [uuid declspec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/uuid-cpp?view=vs-2019), the "type-to-guid" mapping behaves pretty much how one would expect.

But what happens when type `To` is an implementation type derived from `winrt::implements`? There are two extra steps that come into play here.

### The default interface

Step 1 is that `guid_of<T>` returns the guid of T's *default interface*. Interfaces are their own default interface - `default_interface<T>` is the same as `T`. For runtimeclasses, the default interface is [an attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.metadata.defaultattribute?view=winrt-19041) in the winmd, and can be [manually specified](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/midl-3/predefined-attributes#the-default_interface-attribute) in MIDL3, but the typical case is that the default interface of `Widget` is `IWidget`.

### The default interface of winrt::implements

Step 2 is that for a type `T` derived from `winrt::implements`, the default interface of `T` is the default interface of the second type supplied to the template (the first type after the CRTP type). For example,

```cpp
struct Base : implements<Base, IBase> {};
// default_interface<Base> == default_interface<IBase> == IBase

strict Derived1 : implements<Derived1, IDerived, Base> {};
// default_interface<Derived1> == IDerived

struct Derived2 : implements<Derived2, Base, IDerived> {};
// default_interface<Derived2> == IBase

struct Derived1 : implements<Derived1, Base> {};
// default_interface<Derived1> == IBase
```

This is important to remember.

In the example above, note that `Derived2` and `Derived 3` have the same default interface as `Base`. (`Derived3` above is even worse, and a bit of an antipattern - `Derived3` doesn't implement any interfaces of its own, and so there's no need to use `implements` here.) This means that `as<Derived2>()` isn't going to behave the way we might think - C++/WinRT is going to `QueryInterface` for `IBase`, and not `IDerived`, which makes `Base` and `Derived` indistinguishable for the purposes of `as<T>()`. This would lead to runtime ambiguity and all sorts of mayhem if this successfully compiled.

However, `as<Derived2>()` won't compile, because of one last wrinkle: `as<To>()` needs a return type. Again, for projected interfaces/runtimeclasses, this is simple: return `To`. For a raw ABI interface, this is also simple: return `com_ptr<T>`.

### The catch

But for `implements`, we need to remember a detail from `QueryInterface`, the returned pointer must point to the requested interface's vtable (which might be offset in the object's memory layout). At the risk of oversimplifying, `implements` accomplishes this with a template type `produce<D, I>` for each implemented interface (`produce<Derived1, IDerived>` points at `Derived1`'s vtable for `IDerived`). So, the final step is that `as<To>()` casts this ABI offset interface pointer into a `produce<To, default_interface<To>>` pointer, so that the compiler is able to apply the correct offset to safely get back a `To` pointer.

If we take the example code, this means that calling `as<Derived1>()` will cast to `produce<Derived1, IDerived>*`, which can get you back to `Derived1`. But calling `as<Derived2>()` will attempt to cast to `produce<Derived2, IBase>*`, which has no path back to `Derived2`, because `IBase` wasn't one of the interfaces implemented by `Derived2`. Put another way, C++/WinRT will take you from `IBase` to `Base`, because `Base` implements `IBase` via the `implements` type, but it won't take you from `IBase` to `IDerived2`.

### Conclusion

If your implementation type doesn't have a default interface (or doesn't have a unique one), you're going to have a bad time trying to use it with `as<T>()/try_as<T>()`.

At this point, I'm hoping you can see why calling `as<DerivedController>()` isn't quite working for you: it doesn't have its own default interface, making it ambiguous with `Controller` when it comes to `as<T>()`/`QueryInterface`. The reason this worked in C++/CX is it automagically generated a default interface for ref classes. If you want your type to be reachable via `as<T>()`, it needs to have a unique default interface.